# Remove StructItem from tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, struct, delegates

I would like to be able to delete a row/item in a `tableView`.
The `tableView`is populated with a `struct`
Struct:

```
struct Items {
    var name: String = ""
    var count = Int()
}

var itemsInStore : [Items] = []
```

`tableView`is populated like this:

```
  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CheckOutCell") as! CheckOutTableViewCell


        let name = itemsInStore[indexPath.row].name
        let count = itemsInStore[indexPath.row].count

        cell.checkOutLabel.text = "\(count) Pcs \(name)"

        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }
```

Button:
I have been trying different versions of this, but haven't gotten it to work:

```
extension CheckOutViewController: RemoveItemDelegate
{
    func didDeleteItemCell(cell: CheckOutTableViewCell) {

        if let index = itemsInStore.index(where: {$0.name == //Index for the row that is to be deleted })   {
            itemsInCart.remove(at: index)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload the table view

```
if let index = itemsInStore.index(where: {$0.name == //Index for the row that is to be deleted })   {
    itemsInCart.remove(at: index)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Or – preferable – delete the particular row with animation

```
if let index = itemsInStore.index(where: {$0.name == //Index for the row that is to be deleted })   {
    itemsInCart.remove(at: index)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

Comment: I´m having some trouble with getting the index of the struct that is to be deleted. I think if I can get the `indexPath.row` for the `tableView` I can do something like: `...(where: {$0.name == cell.checkOutLabel.text`... Or I'm I totally wrong here? And if I'm not wrong, how can I access the  `cell.checkOutLabel.text`?

Comment: I have no idea where or from where the method `didDeleteItemCell` is called. You should not get any value from the *view*   (the cell), get it from the *model* (the data source array). The best way to retrieve button clicks or other UI changes is a callback closure created in `cellForRow`